# No response from php while uploading image using jQuery ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, image-uploading

I am trying to upload image using ajax call and then doing the server part in php. I was first searching on how to do this and i ended on the below specified link

[Uploading image using ajax call](http://www.formget.com/ajax-image-upload-php/)

I have implemented it but file type is not being set on call to php page and its returning nothing which means i guess is that file index is not being set.

Form

```
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="imageUploadForm">
    <input type="file" name="imageUpload" class="imageUpload" accept="image/*">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger saveUploadImageBtn" value="Save">
</form>
```

JQuery Code

```
$('body').on('click' , '.saveUploadImageBtn' , function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url:"imageUpload.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: new FormData($('form#imageUploadForm')[0]),
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
});
```

PHP Code

```
<?php
   if(isset($_FILES["file"]["type"])) {
       $validextensions = array("jpeg", "jpg", "png");
       $temp = explode('.', $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
       $file_extension = end($temp);
       if((($_FILES['file']['type'] == 'image/png') || ($_FILES['file']['type'] == 'image/jpg') || ($_FILES['name']['type'] == 'image/jpeg')) && ($_FILES['file']['size'] < 100000) && in_array($file_extension, $validextensions))    {
    if($_FILES['file']['error'] > 0) {
        echo 'Return Code: '.$_FILES['file']['error'].'<br/>';
    }
    else {
        if(file_exists('images/'.$_FILES['file']['name'])) {
            echo $_FILES['file']['name'].' already exists';
        }
        else {
            $sourcePath = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
            $targetPath = 'image/'.$_FILES['file']['name'];
            move_uploaded_file($sourcePath, $targetPath);
            echo 'Image Uploaded Successfully'.'<br/>'.'File Name: '.$_FILES['file']['name'].'<br/>'.'File Type: '.$_FILES['name']['type'].'<br/>'.'File Size: '.$_FILES['file']['size'].'<br/>'.' Temp File: '.$FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        }
    }
}
else {
    echo 'Invalid image size or type';
}
```

}
?>

What mistake am i committing and why the file index is not setting up ?
Anyone please help me out here

Thank you

Comment: try to use `AjaxForm` jQuery plugin, it is simple http://malsup.com/jquery/form/

Comment: first of all, see a vardump of $_FILES. do you see anything there?